Connecting AWS RDS database to WIX Velo but have error message: Access to database denied - probably wrong credentials
I've been following the Wix Velo tutorial connecting an Amazon RDS database to Wix but I have received the following message:
Connection Status
Access to database denied - probably wrong credentials, sql message: Access denied for user 'admin '@'ec2-107-22-48-59.compute-1.amazonaws.com' (using password: YES)
I don't know what to do.
I have tried following the tutorial again: https://dev.wix.com/docs/develop-websites/articles/databases/external-databases/overview/integrating-external-databases-with-your-wix-site but this did not work.
I also added additional values to the secrets manager as per recommendation as shown, this did not help.
I am expecting for the message to change from Red to green.

I think you could left ticked the option to create attached the RDS database to an EC2 Instance due to your admin user saying ...@'ec2-107-22-48-59.compute-1.amazonaws.com'
You could re-check the cluster to be connected to a VPC and to has public access. I think you should have a correct security group since the 'access denied' error is coming from the engine.
Also try modifying the user to accept connections from anywhere.

Hi Thanks for the suggestions, can you provide instructions on how to do this please?
